# Is it possible to change Type to a given type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

When I have a boxed value such as:

```
object input = 31.33M;
```

I can convert it to a convertible type with this method:

```
public static T ToType<T>( object value)
 {
  return (T) Convert.ChangeType(value,typeof (T));
 }
```

so both:

```
Console.WriteLine (ToType<double>(input));
Console.WriteLine (ToType<decimal>(input));
```

will return

```
31.33 //as double
31.33 //as decimal
```

*(let's leave aside the precision issues)*

Okay.

But now I'm facing *( I'm using WebAPI which exposes method descriptor and its argument types)* a situation where I have a *given* type.

So now I have :

```
Type SomeoneSaysMyTypeIs=typeof(decimal)
```

But now I *can't* use generic type argument.

**Question**

How can I enhance my method to work for: (*pseudo code*)

```
ToType(SomeoneSaysMyTypeIs,input); //return type :decimal  , not object
```

*I've found solutions but with a lot of `if's`...*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be I didn't understand your question correctly (please tell so if I did), but what about introducing another method:

```
public static object ToType(object value, Type t)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

Which is as you see just the same as calling [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) directly:

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
```

Comment: And just to add, you obviously have to return an `object` because the required generic type `T` is unknown - you just have a variable of type `Type`

Comment: @Rhumborl: Beside it is impossible, it doesn't make any sens to do so :).

Comment: no . I need it to be as a decimal return type not object!

Comment: It is a `decimal` returning... It's just boxed as `object`.

Comment: a boxed one. the webapi parameter is expecting decimal not object .

Comment: @RoyiNamir hence my comment - if you want to _use_ it as a decimal, you either need to have a generic method or cast the return value to decimal in the calling code (or invoke the webapi method through reflection, which doesn't smell right)

Comment: If the service is expecting that, why do you need all the converting then?

Comment: the json parser treats 3.33 as double . but the actual parameter (in the method) is decimal!. so I read by reflection the real type which is decimal and then I need to run the method in myquestion. ( so it changes 3.33 as double to decimal)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That might be due to JSON not supporting decimals... See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm) for example.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I know that. but it doesn't prevent me from "fixing" the type in my webapi. :-) ( hence my question)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You might be better off writing a custom converter. Like [here](http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/using-a-custom-jsonconverter-to-fix-bad-json-results/) (if you are using JSON.NET).

Comment: @PatrickHofman just a visualization : im invoking dynamically another action from another controller  , so I have the values via json , and then I invoke each action with parameter but as you can see - there is a mismatch between accepting type and sending type. hence my question. http://i.imgur.com/Wa20lOz.png

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Okay, it seems you workarounded it. Does it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68223/discussion-between-patrick-hofman-and-royi-namir).

Comment: Yes. (Just wanted to know if the return type can be according to a given argument type)